# add accordion to gui builder form

Tags: codenameone

There's no accordion in the component palette of gui builder 6.1 so I can't drag it onto the form, and the layered layout manager in the No Touch section doesn't have a name so I can't add it in code.
How can I add an accordion to the layered layout in a gui builder form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GUI Builder allows you to drag a custom components into the GUI. Just pick the "custom component" from the palette and drag it into place.

Once you do that (and build the project) you will have a method with the signature:

```
private Component create_ComponentName() {
    return new MyComponent();
}
```

Here you can return any arbitrary component instance, bind listeners and do any initialization code you want. The GUI builder will only be used as a layout tool in the case of that specific component and you would have the full power to place anything there.

See https://www.codenameone.com/blog/partners-demos-custom-gui-components-iphone-old-deprecation.html

Comment: I think I figured it out.  
In the custom component method I returned an accordion like so:  
return new com.codename1.components.Accordion();  
  
But elsewhere I can't use accordion methods like gui_Custom.removeAll() because gui_Custom is type component and not type accordion.  
  
I tried this and it didn't work:  
Accordion accr = gui_Custom;  
but this does work:  
Accordion accr = (Accordion)gui_Custom;  
accr.removeAll();